# How to add one code block as prologue to another code block, for noweb style expansion of code blocks while evaluating with Org-Babel?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

While evaluating the fn-main in the following example, I want the some-fn code to be appended at the beginning of the fn-main block, for expansion before evaluation.

```
#+NAME: some-fn
#+BEGIN_SRC C
    void printother() {
        printf("WOrld");
    }
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: fn-main
#+BEGIN_SRC C :noweb yes :main no :prologue "<<some-fn>>"
    int main() {
        printother();
        printf("Hello");
    }
#+END_SRC
```

Currently, evaluation of fn-main leads to the following error:

`` /tmp/ccAuvLn1.o: In function `main':
C-src-5927aNL.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `printother'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/bin/bash: /tmp/babel-5927f7v/C-bin-5927nXR: No such file or directory ``
 
Final desired expanded block before execution:

```
    void printother() {
        printf("WOrld");
    }
    int main() {
        printother();
        printf("Hello");
    }
```

The `:noweb eval` argument applies to the entire block, and this eliminates the possibility of having some blocks tangled as well as executed. It should work but gives me an error currently, `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#+NAME: some-fn
#+BEGIN_SRC C
    void printother() {
        printf("WOrld");
    }
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: fn-main
#+BEGIN_SRC C :noweb yes
    <<some-fn>>
    int main() {
        printother();
        printf("Hello");
    }
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: fn-main
: WOrldHello
```

Comment: Maybe I did not emphasize that I want it in the prologue header argument `only`. In the example you present `<<some-fn>>` will be exported & tangled(if enabled) too, while `:prologue` only gets appended for evaluation and is discarded when tangling or exporting. In the desired final output, I mention that it must be before execution, but `prologue` means I only want it while executing.
`:noweb eval` should do something similar, but it would mess up with the code blocks I don't want to be added merely as prologue. in practice, it gives me the error I mentioned at the end of the question.

Comment: Sorry - that was not obvious to me. However, AFAICT `ob-C` does *not* implement the `:prologue` header.